# な Adjectives - Only in present tense?

Tags: na-adjectives

I've doubt about な.

I've to use it only when I'm talking in present tense?

Example:

> １）きれいな人だ
>   ２）きれいな人だった

The second one is valid?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What has led you to believe the second is invalid?

Comment: @Sjiveru I'm reading Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese book, and I came across with  [this](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/adjectives).
There is a part that says `Remember to attach 「な」 for positive non-past tense`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/61620/past-tense-na-adjective-noun

Comment: @ MatayoshiMariano I think she says きれいだったな人 is unnatural.

Comment: @kandyman Yep, totally duplicate. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @YuuichiTam Just so you know, Tae Kim is a man.